# VS 2010 to VS2012 and Project Name Change - Area forms HttpPost no longer working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I just created a new project in VS 2012 - basically replicated what I had in 2010 but changed all the namespaces to a different project name. All is working except my Area forms are no longer being directed to the HttpPost version of the action. Instead, the submit is redirecting to the HttpGet. Any ideas? My Areas appear to be registered correctly and no code has changed (other than namespace references).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out! Not sure why this didn't work, but for my other routes, I was using LowercaseRoutesMVC4 and didn't apply this to my Area routing. Not sure why this would break it, but it seems to be working now.